# Decomposing the effect of x on y

Tags: anova, structural-equation-modeling

I have an independent variable `x`, and a dependent variable `y` which is the sum of two variables, `y = y1 + y2`.

There is a significant correlation between `y` and `x`. I would like to know how much of this correlation is accounted for by (i) the correlation between `x` and `y1` and `x`, and (ii) that between `x` and `y2`.

Does anyone know an appropriate technique?

Comment: Do you have access to the underlying y variables?

Comment: This question is problematic for an interesting reason: it is possible for $y$ to have an (arbitrarily) high correlation with $x$, yet for neither $y_1$ nor $y_2$ to have any appreciable correlation with $x$! (For example, choose uncorrelated $x$ and $y_1$ with Var$(x)=1$ and Var$(y_1)=\sigma^2\gg 1$. Define $y_2=x-y_1$. The correlation of $x$ and $y$ is $1$ but the correlation of $x$ and $y_2$ is $1/\sqrt{1+\sigma^2}\approx 0$.) How, then, would it even make sense to try to "account for" or partition the $(x,y)$ correlation among $y_1$ and $y_2$?

Comment: I see your point. That argument holds because of the large variance of `y_1`. But note that the covariance sums out nicely: `cov(X, Y1+Y2) = cov(X, Y1) + cov(X, Y2)`. Conceptually, then, it seems that it is possible to partition the covariance. I would welcome an answer using different statistics than correlation coefficients. (Or can rephrase the question.)

Comment: @gung - yes I do.